# dplyr -- calculate difference in means by group across all columns in a tibble

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble with about 100 variables in columns. I'd like to calculate the difference in the mean value of each variable according to a group. I can do this easily one column at a time but but I'm unsure how to apply it across all the columns at once. E.g., doing each column:

```
library(tidyverse)
foo <- tibble(var1 = rnorm(100),
              var2 = rnorm(100),
              var3 = rnorm(100),
              groupID = rep(c("A","B"),50))
# make one var different for example
foo <- foo %>% mutate(var3 = case_when(groupID=="A" ~ var3 + 1,
                                       groupID=="B" ~ var3 - 1))

res <- bind_rows(foo %>% 
                   group_by(groupID) %>% 
                   summarise(avg = mean(var1)) %>% 
                   summarise(meanDiff = diff(avg)),
                 foo %>% 
                   group_by(groupID) %>% 
                   summarise(avg = mean(var2)) %>% 
                   summarise(meanDiff = diff(avg)),
                 foo %>%
                   group_by(groupID) %>% 
                   summarise(avg = mean(var3)) %>% 
                   summarise(meanDiff = diff(avg)))

res
```

How can I do all the columns at once and return `res`?

This was my solution but it feels clunky.

```
foo <- tibble(
  var1 = rnorm(100),
  var2 = rnorm(100),
  var3 = rnorm(100),
  groupID = rep(c("A", "B"), 50)) %>%
  mutate(var3 = case_when(groupID == "A" ~ var3 + 1,
                          groupID == "B" ~ var3 - 1)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-groupID)

res <- foo %>% 
  group_by(groupID,name) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(diff_value = avg[groupID == "A"] - avg[groupID == "B"])

res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your actual dataset's column names are as consistent as the ones in your toy example, something like the following should work:

```
res1 <- foo %>%
  group_by(groupID) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("var"),
                   .fns = mean,
                   .names = "avg_{.col}")) %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with("avg"),
                   .fns = diff,
                   .names = "meanDiff_{.col}")) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("meanDiff"),
                      values_to = "meanDiff") %>%
  select(-name)

all.equal(res, res1) # compare against your previous results
```